# InputStream Always returns nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, inputstream, assets

```
    SentenceModel model = null;
    InputStream modelIn = null;

    AssetManager assManager = context.getAssets();

    try {
        modelIn = assManager.open("en-sent.bin");
        model = new SentenceModel(modelIn);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (modelIn != null) {
            try {
                modelIn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //initializes sentence detector
    SentenceDetectorME sentenceDetector = new SentenceDetectorME(model);

//Stacktrace 
08-03 14:25:23.842 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: en-sent.bin
08-03 14:25:23.842 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
08-03 14:25:23.842 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:313)
08-03 14:25:23.842 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:287)
08-03 14:25:23.842 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.gigstudios.newssummary.WordCounter.makeSentences(WordCounter.java:35)
08-03 14:25:23.842 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.gigstudios.newssummary.Article.<init>(Article.java:19)
08-03 14:25:23.842 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.gigstudios.newssummary.ArticleReceiver.receiveNewsArticles(ArticleReceiver.java:87)
08-03 14:25:23.842 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.gigstudios.newssummary.ArticleReceiver.<init>(ArticleReceiver.java:37)
08-03 14:25:23.842 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.gigstudios.newssummary.MainActivity.fetchNews(MainActivity.java:114)
08-03 14:25:23.842 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.gigstudios.newssummary.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:52)
08-03 14:25:23.843 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
08-03 14:25:23.843 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-03 14:25:23.843 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
08-03 14:25:23.843 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
08-03 14:25:23.843 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-03 14:25:23.843 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
08-03 14:25:23.843 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-03 14:25:23.843 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-03 14:25:23.844 27210-27210/com.gigstudios.newssummary E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.gigstudios.newssummary, PID: 27210
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorFactory opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel.getFactory()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorME.<init>(SentenceDetectorME.java:86)
                                                                                at com.gigstudios.newssummary.WordCounter.makeSentences(WordCounter.java:50)
                                                                                at com.gigstudios.newssummary.Article.<init>(Article.java:19)
                                                                                at com.gigstudios.newssummary.ArticleReceiver.receiveNewsArticles(ArticleReceiver.java:87)
                                                                                at com.gigstudios.newssummary.ArticleReceiver.<init>(ArticleReceiver.java:37)
                                                                                at com.gigstudios.newssummary.MainActivity.fetchNews(MainActivity.java:114)
                                                                                at com.gigstudios.newssummary.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:52)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

I have been trying to fix this issue for hours and have gotten nowhere. In the above code sample model is always null and the en-sent.bin file doesn't seem to be read into the modelIn object. My bin file is in an assets folder currently. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the Java stack trace associated with your exception.

Comment: Add stacktrace on question please.

Comment: @Julian I added the stack trace.

Comment: @Jared Is `en-sent.bin` on the root directory of your application? Or is it inside a folder?

Comment: @Julian It's in a folder called assets along with the .gradle, .idea, .app etc folders

Comment: @Jared I believe that the answer by Jason will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution! I put the bin file in the "raw" directory and...

Instead of:

```
        modelIn = assManager.open("en-sent.bin");
        model = new SentenceModel(modelIn);
```

Use:

```
        modelIn = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.en_sent);
        model = new SentenceModel(modelIn);
```

Works perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

You need to:

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;
StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("en-sent.bin")));

        // read
        String mLine; 
        while ((mLine = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    sbuilder.append(mLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
//log
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
             try {
                 reader.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
 //log
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain why they need to do this and how it relates to the exception they are seeing with their current code.

Comment: @Jason What is "sbuilder" and "buffer"? I don't understand how to implement this into my code.

Comment: I've edited the code, if you whant to open an assets file to InputStream like your example, 

 InputStream modelIn = null;
AssetManager assManager = context.getAssets();

        modelIn = assManager.open("en-sent.bin");

you need to read it with the InputStreamReader
In sbuilder you have all data from the file to string so you can read it;

Comment: @Jason my code still does not work. I don't know how to incorporate my modelIn and model variables with this code. I think i need a FileInputStream but this code gives me a StringBuilder. It also can't file the jar file it seems like.